# Is it possible to get the value of a variable in a loop inside a function into a global variable?

Tags: html, function, variables, javascript

I need to get the result of a variable after it has been through a loop, I have tried getting its value by making it a global variable but it's value doesn't change. Is this possible at all?

Here is my code, I am trying to get the value of the variable t:

```
var t;

function processSplashbacks() {
    var splashbacks = document.worktopForm.splashbacks.value;   
    for (t = 1; t <= splashbacks; t++){
        var splashbackInfo = '<label> Length: </label><input type="text" id="length' + t + '" value="0"/>(cm)<br /><label> Width: </label><input type="text" name="width' + t + '" value="0"/>(cm)<br /><br />';
        document.getElementById("splashWidLen").innerHTML += 'Splashback ' + t + ' dimensions<br />' + splashbackInfo;
    }
}

function deleteSplashbacks() {
    document.getElementById("splashWidLen").innerHTML = "";
}

console.log(t);
```

Thanks!

Comment: So do you ever call this code?

Comment: I don't see where you are calling processSplashbacks. Is that additional code? Also, what is t set to originally?

Comment: I call it through a button and the onClick method

Comment: <input type="button" value="Add Splashbacks" onClick="processSplashbacks()"/>

Comment: Do you call `console.log(t)` in your onClick method as well? Right now, you're only calling it once, when the page loads.

Comment: I have only used console.log(t) to test what the value of t is, it comes out as undefined. And the t is only set originally within the loop as a value of 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
<input type="button" value="Add Splashbacks" onClick="processSplashbacks(); console.log(t);"/>
```

From what I see, you're only calling `console.log(t)` in one place. It only logs it when the page loads, which is before the user clicks on the button. You have to call `console.log(t);` again after the function call.

That said, a global variable is probably not the best solution. You would be better off making that function `return t;`, and then log the return, like this:

```
<input type="button" value="Add Splashbacks" onClick="console.log(processSplashbacks());"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

So you are just trying to set the variable as a global variable?

This should work: `window.t = t;`
Just put that inside the loop and increment.

I'm not sure how useful this actually would be though. Are you sure you want to be able to access the loop control variable?

Comment: I will try this. I need to get the value of t to see how many new inputs have been made so I can add up the value of them

Answer (score 1):

The 4 statements in your code are:

- declaration of t
- declaration of two functions
- printing t

They are all run when the page loads, but declaring a function does not execute it... Whenever the function is executed, it will be after your `console.log(t)` statement.

now if you write this:

```
onClick="processSplashbacks(); console.log(t);"
```

then it should work

Answer (score 1):

The function is defined, and you log the variable to the console before the function has run.  Instead, you can rewrite the function to define and return its own t, and then the onclick handler can display it to the log.